# Do we require to eliminate share drive access to PCI users?

Tags: pci-dss

Do we really require to eliminate the share drive access to the PCI users.
We have a file server outside PCI VLAN. But PCI users have access to it.

We dont have any DLP solutions. Does the PCI standard requires to eliminate file servers?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't require you to *eliminate* them, but if PCI-scoped user systems with PAN data on them can freely save files to them, then the file servers are in PCI scope and have to be subjected to full DSS compliance.

...and if your newly PCI-scoped file servers are *also* accessible to non-PCI-scoped user systems, then those non-PCI-scoped user systems are in PCI scope and have to be subjected to full DSS compliance.

...and so on, and so forth.

Comment: There are 3 things to look at when determining if something is in or out of scope for PCI
If a system stores, processes, or transmits cardholder data.
IF a system has access to a system that stores, processes or transmits cardholder data.
If a system can impact the security of the CDE. If any one of those is true then it's in scope.

Comment: Even if the server would be read-only for the PCI users, it would still be in-scope because a non-PCI user could save a virus to the server that causes havoc inside the PCI enviroment.